# Проблема с запросами на сервер

Tags: http, сокет, c++

Написал Socket-клиент на C++. К серверам коннектится нормально, но когда отправляю запрос получаю либо код ошибки "400 Bad Request". Например, url = 77.120.111.7 а port = 80 отправляю запрос "GET / HTTP/1.0" получаю, либо "400 Bad Request", либо "пустоту".

```
int main(){

char url[100];
int port;

char name[30];
std::cout << "Url: ";
cin >> url;

std::cout << "Port: ";
cin >> port;

WSADATA WsaData;
if (int err = WSAStartup (MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WsaData) != 0)
{
        std::cout << "Socket not Loaded!\n";
        }
gethostname(name, 30);     
   int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock == -1){
        std::cout << "Error! Socket no created.\n" ;      
               }
  hostent *hp=NULL;
  hp = gethostbyname("localhost");

sockaddr_in addr;
addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
addr.sin_port=htons(port);
addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(url);

int locate; 
locate = connect(sock, (sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

if (locate < 0){

        std::cout << "Fatal Error!\n";   
           system("pause");
           }else{
    char cut[30];
    char get[100000];
    string hosted;
    std::cout << "Connected...  " << url << "\n";

              do{

                  std::cout << "Output: ";
                  cin >> cut;

             send(sock, cut, 30, 0);

             recv(sock, get, 512, 0);
             std::cout << "Command:  " << get << "\n";

             }while(locate == 0);

                 }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ох... Задача: послать строку `GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n` на сервер и получить ответ. Т.е. не надо устраивать карусель send/recv -- один раз send, и сколько получится -- recv. Обнаруживать конец страницы -- возврат 0 из recv. Тут оно даже не анализируется, а идёт цикл, пока `locate==0` (И кто бы эту locate изменил?) Там ещё явно не так, как задумывалось ведёт себя конструкция `cin >> cut;`. И осторожнее с концами строк <CR><LF>
Вот текст с правками, если будут вопросы, постараюсь ответить.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <winsock.h>
#include <ipexport.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char url[100];
    int port;

    char name[30];
    std::cout << "Url: ";
    cin >> url;

    std::cout << "Port: ";
    cin >> port;
    cin.get(); /* !!!! */

    WSADATA WsaData;
    if (int err = WSAStartup (MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WsaData) != 0) {
        std::cout << "Socket not Loaded!\n";
    }

    gethostname(name, 30); 
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sock == -1){
        std::cout << "Error! Socket no created.n" ; 
    }
    hostent *hp=NULL; hp = gethostbyname("localhost");

    sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port=htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(url);

    int locate;
    locate = connect(sock, (sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

    if (locate < 0) {
        std::cout << "Fatal Error!\n";   
        system("pause");
    } else {
        string cut;
        char get[100000];
        int l;
        string hosted;
        std::cout << "Connected...  " << url << endl;
        std::cout << "Output: " << flush;
        getline(cin, cut);
        cut += "\r\n\r\n";
        send(sock, cut.data(), cut.length(), 0);
        do{
            l = recv(sock, get, 512, 0);
            std::cout << "Command:  " << get << endl;
        } while (l);
    }
}
```

Правки заметите. И ещё, откуда манера писать `<< "\n"`?

Comment: что означают функции data(),  getline(), length() только хочу знать подробное описание подскажите литературу!

Comment: Я примерно понимаю по синтаксису что они означают но, хочется полностью изучить возможности и значения а так же подскажите литературу по теме "Обработки строк" и "Передачи данных". Зарание спасибо. "И ещё, откуда манера писать << "\n"?" - не знаю раньше писал "endl" а как увидел что можно и так "\n", от туда и манера. Я просто сначала учил PHP а потом C++ и мне это показалось удобнее.

Comment: А разве "getline(cin, cut)" это правильно, может так cin.getline(cut, sizeof(cut)); А насчет locate все правильно это дает возможность отправлять больше чем один запрос!

Comment: data() и length() -- методы класса string. getline() -- функция из библиотеки string. cin.getline -- метод из istream, но там cut д.б. типа `char *`. Насчёт `cout << "\n"`, endl кроме вывода конца строки ещё делает flush, т.е. вывод буфер в поток. А литература -- так по C++. Я для справок пользуюсь www.cplusplus.com, но с хелпами по C++ вероятно лучше подскажут другие.